# Android: a class extending Framelayout

Tags: android

In android, we can create different type of class which is either activity, service, fragment etc. My question is, if make a class extending Framelayout. is there any easy way to communicate from one frame layout to another one. since it's not an activity. We can't use intent.

p.s i'm doing it for overlay and the parent class/ or main one is a surface view to display a video. Thanks in advance. (Android beginner)

Comment: try https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: care to explain? @vincentzhou